Algorithm to compare multiplications of powers of primes
Is there an algorithm to compare two numeric expressions that follow these rules:

The expressions are multiplications of powers.
Every power is a power of a prime number.
The two expressions do not share any primes.

The comparison in question is comparison of the resulting multiplication products - which is larger?
An example of two such expressions is: (7^21)*(2^49) and (5^26)*(3^31).
The idea is to compare such expressions with the powers being quite large, up to 2^64.

If you write the code in Python, you can use its standard unlimited integers ((7**21)*(2**49) = 314433368169351194914958222557184).  If such integers aren't available, you could work with the logarithm. a < b is equivalent to log(a) < log(b) (for a and b strictly positive numbers). log((7^21)*(2^49)) = 21*log(7) + 49*log(2).

If you don't mind the possibility that some values close together might give incorrect results, you could calculate the logs using log(x^y) = y*log(x) and compare those..

How many prime powers can there be in the product?

@SimonGoater in the practical case there would be up to 4 primes: 2,3,5,7. This is because I'm actually interested in comparing products of numbers 2-9.

Close voters: Questions asking for recommendations of libraries and tools are off-topic as they are opinion-based and invite spam. Algorithms are not in that list. It's totally legit to ask about algorithms.

I would suggest the log method but using https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects to get sufficient precision. With 2^64 being the power, you'll be dealing with logarithms of size 10^22. And a difference of 1 in the numbers will be a difference of 1/10^22 in the output. So 45 digits of precision should guarantee no errors.

you can compute logarithm with arbitrary precision with this algorithm https://math.stackexchange.com/a/59596/674964

As commented, you can use the log() function and create a compare method:
import math

def _cmp(A, B):
    asum = sum(a * math.log(p) for p, a in A)
    bsum = sum(b * math.log(q) for q, b in B)
    if asum > bsum:
        return 'A > B'
    elif asum < bsum:
        return 'A < B'
    else:
        return 'A = B'


A = [(7, 21), (2, 49)]
B = [(5, 26), (3, 31)]

print(_cmp(A, B))

Prints
A < B

Method 1: You could use a series expansion for the powers to approximate a solution and compare them. We could also take the logarithm on both sides: log(LHS) =/</> log(RHS) => LHS =/</> RHS <=> exp(LHS) =/</> exp(RHS), so comparison would stay the same:
a1^b1 * a2^b2 * ... = / > / < c1^d1 * c2^d2 * ... => log(a1)*b1 + log(a2)*b2 + ... = / > / < log(c1)*d1 + log(c2)*d2 + ...

This would be one method.
If these numbers are also to big you could take the logarithm to a higher base (as far as i know the only higher bases in js are 2, e (around 2.7) and 10 aka only one is higher), or (Method 2:) raise both sides to the power of 1/n where n>1 (for the same reason as taking the logarithm). That what changes is that the exponents would be multiplied by 1/n, so if the bases are integers bigger then 1 (wich is the case), then LHS > LHS^(1/n) and RHS > RHS^(1/n).
Explanation of the Code for Method 1
Assuming that exp(LHS) = a1^b1 * a2^b2 * ... and exp(RHS) = a1^b1 * a2^b2 * ...:
Let's say that in the input fields the bases and exponents are separated by a notation, so we could take the contents of the input fields (part 1) and then split the resulting string at the notations (part 2). We receive lists of values ​​that we can use.
The lists only contain the values ​​component by component and we can put them together by adding the individual components to the terms that still need to be added. Each of the terms would look like this: Math.log(basen[k]) * exponentn[k]. We now have to add these together over the number of elements in the list, i.e. from k = 0 to k = length - 1. (Part 4) I defined indexn as this length. (Part 3)
Now we only have to compare the results (wich we can easily do via if query or if else query) and set the content of the div. (Part 5)
Explanation of the Code for Method 2
Assuming that n is the degree of the n.th root (not the n.th power): Part 1, 2, 3 and 5 are the same as in method 1. We would calculate the terms (Math.pow(basen[k], exponentn[k])) and multiply all of them together. Important would be that the starting point (the declared LHS and RHS) are equal to one. '' + a == a and 1 * a == a are true but '' * a == a shouldn't. (Part 4)
Code


function compare() {
  /* Get's your input: */
  let degree = document.getElementById('input-degree').value;
  let bases1 = document.getElementById('input-bases-1').value;
  let bases2 = document.getElementById('input-bases-2').value;
  let exponents1 = document.getElementById('input-exponents-1').value;
  let exponents2 = document.getElementById('input-exponents-2').value;

  /* Splits the input into an array of entert number separated through a " ": */
  let base1 = bases1.split(' ');
  let base2 = bases2.split(' ');
  let exponent1 = exponents1.split(' ');
  let exponent2 = exponents2.split(' ');

  /* Get's length of list: */
  var index1 = base1.length;
  var index2 = base2.length;
  
  /* Check if degree has changend: */
  if (degree == 2) { /* If unchanged degree */
    /* Adds all terms together for the LHS and RHS: */
    
    var LHS = ''; /* declare */
    var RHS = ''; /* declare */
    for (let k = 0; k < index1; k++) {
      LHS = LHS + Math.log(base1[k]) * exponent1[k];
    };
    for (let g = 0; g < index2; g++) {
      RHS = RHS + Math.log(base2[g]) * exponent2[g];
    };
  } else { /* If changed degree */
    var LHS = 1; /* declare */
    var RHS = 1; /* declare */
    for (let k = 0; k < index1; k++) {
      LHS = LHS * Math.pow(base1[k], exponent1[k] / n);
    };
    for (let g = 0; g < index2; g++) {
      RHS = RHS * Math.pow(base2[g], exponent2[g] / n);
    };
  }

  /* Check relation: */
  if (LHS == RHS) {
    return document.getElementById('compareison').innerHTML = "LHS = RHS";
  } else if (LHS < RHS) {
    return document.getElementById('compareison').innerHTML = "LHS < RHS";
    }
  else if (LHS > RHS) {
      return document.getElementById('compareison').innerHTML = "LHS > RHS";
  } else {
    return document.getElementById('compareison').innerHTML = "Error!";
  }
}
#input-bases-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5pt;
  left: 5pt;
  
  height: 10pt;
  width: 100pt;
}
#input-exponents-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5pt;
  left: 115pt;
  
  height: 10pt;
  width: 100pt;
}
#input-bases-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25pt;
  left: 5pt;
  
  height: 10pt;
  width: 100pt;
}
#input-exponents-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25pt;
  left: 115pt;
  
  height: 10pt;
  width: 100pt;
}
#input-degree {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15pt;
  left: 225pt;
  
  height: 10pt;
  width: 50pt;
}
#compare-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45pt;
  left: 77pt;
  
  height: 15pt;
  width: 75pt;
}
#compareison {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65pt;
  left: 5pt;
  
  width: 200pt;
  
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<input id = "input-bases-1" placeholder = "bases a1 a2 a3 ..."></input>
<input id = "input-exponents-1" placeholder = "exponents b1 b2 b3 ..."></input>
<input id = "input-bases-2" placeholder = "bases c1 c2 c3 ..."></input>
<input id = "input-exponents-2" placeholder = "exponents d1 d2 d3 ..."></input>
<input id = "input-degree" type = "number" value = "1" placeholder = "degree"></input>
<button id = "compare-button" type = "button" onclick = "compare()">Compare</button>
<div id = "compareison">Compareison</div>



